# Error going to the correct page in cucumber test on RoR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber

I have a RoR page with some cucumber tests. The page appears to work.
The link that the human takes to get to the page is:

```
= link_to "Override Password", edit_admin_client_password_path(@client), :class => "button"
```

The cucumber step that I believe is SUPPOSED to go there appears to be giving me empty HTML...

```
Given /^I navigate to the Clients Password Page for "(.*?)"$/ do |client_email|
  @current_client = Client.find_by(email: client_email)
  visit edit_admin_client_password_path(@current_client)
  puts edit_admin_client_password_path(@current_client)
  puts Capybara.current_session.html
end
```

This gives me:

```
  /admin/client_passwords/1/edit
  <html><head></head><body></body></html>
```

I believe that the user is user 1, because it's being generated by the test. I've checked before and user 1 appears to have the correct email, etc..

When, at the web page, I go to `http://localhost:3000/admin/client_passwords/6203/edit` it goes to the correct place, which I assume is the correct thing.

So, why is this giving me an empty HTML?

ETA: the visit **IS** changing the page. Before the visit, the html is the home page...

ETA 2: After comments by @thomas-walpole, It appears that I am logging in, I'm using the controller correctly, and I'm trying to produce the view correctly.

HOWEVER: When I add -puts "foobie" to the view haml.html file, I have:

```
    - puts "foobie"
    - password = Curl::Easy.perform("http://www.dinopass.com/password/simple").body_str
    - puts "bletch"
```

I get "foobie" but not "bletch".

I'm using curb. Is there a thing that CURL won't work in cucumber testing?

ETA 3:

I've edited the `- password =` line:

```
- password = @client.id != 1 ?  Curl::Easy.perform("http://www.dinopass.com/password/simple").body_str : 'Password1'
```

On the assumption that userID 1 doesn't actually exist in the real system.... There's probably a better way of doing that test...

Comment: What URL is the page actually on? -- `Capybara.current_session.current_url`

Comment: http://127.0.0.1:51947/admin/client_passwords/1/edit

Comment: Ok - so it's at the correct URL but your page is blank probably means something wrong in your controller - Either you aren't configured correctly for elements to be accessible in both the app and the tests (Rails version specific), you have an error in your controller/view, or you aren't actaully logged in - Your `logs/test.log` should show any errors.

Comment: I am going to the edit method of the client_passwords_controller, and I AM logged in, at least before I try to go to the client_passwords/1/edit, I'm on the page I go to right after logging in... (via viewing the HTML of the session) ...

Comment: Also, when I put a - puts statement int my edit.html.haml, it gets put, so it's at least TRYING to generate the page?

Comment: Without knowing where in your template you’re putting the `puts` it’s tough to know anything else - the logs/test.log would help too

Comment: Sorry, thought it would be better to add details to the question itself for formatting...

Comment: And what does the logfile (log/test.log) show from when it attempts to render that view?

Comment: Perhaps I need to protect that line, and just hardcode password to something in the "testing" case?

Comment: I don't see any errors, but it's a big messy file... I'll add a "fix" I made and see if that's considered "correct"...

Comment: Just delete the log - run the failing test again and look at the end for where it's rendering the edit view

Comment: The log doesn't show anything interesting...